# Permission Denied of webkit_server folder even if all permissions to rwx

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-permissions, ubuntu-18.04, dryscrape

This is the error I keep getting while executing my python script:

```
**[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/e/projects/python/phising/main/phising/lib/python3.6/site-packages/webkit_server'**
```

These are the permissions of files and folder inside webkit_server

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1  1086 Feb 25 21:11 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1   136 Feb 25 21:11 MANIFEST.in
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1  2102 Feb 25 21:11 README.md
drwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1  4096 Feb 25 21:11 build
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1   253 Feb 25 21:11 build.sh
drwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1  4096 Feb 25 21:11 debian
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1  1721 Feb 25 21:11 setup.py
drwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1  4096 Feb 25 21:11 src
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1    75 Feb 25 21:11 webkit_server.pro
-rwxrwxrwx 1 username1 username1 18087 Feb 25 21:11 webkit_server.py
```

Comment: What operation is the code trying to perform?  i.e. trying to create that directory will fail because it already exists; trying to remove it will fail because it contains files, etc.  Show us the line of code that causes the error.

Comment: @JohnGordon it is just trying execute the files inside. That directory is actually python library which my code uses.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to execute the directory _itself_, not a file inside the directory.